# C# - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

Tags: c#, vbscript

when i try to run the code below, I am getting

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type"

error at runtime.

How to handle this exception and why my `objectName` is null here? I am expecting `objectName` to hold the value of local user account on my computer.

```
namespace Users
{
    class EnableDisableUsers
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter user account to be enabled or disabled");
            var user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter E to enable and D to disable the user account");
            string enableStr = Console.ReadLine();
            bool enable;
            var computer = ".";

            if (enableStr.Equals("E") || enableStr.Equals("e"))
            {
                enable = true;

                var objectName = "WinNT://" + computer + "/" + user + ",user"; 
                dynamic objUser = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(objectName));
                objUser.AccountDisabled = false;
                objUser.SetInfo();
                Console.WriteLine(user + " Enabled = " + result.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (enableStr.Equals("D") || enableStr.Equals("d"))
            {
                enable = false; 
                var objectName = "WinNT://" + computer + "/" + user + ",user";
                dynamic objUser = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(objectName));
                objUser.AccountDisabled = true;
                objUser.SetInfo();
                Console.WriteLine(user + " Enabled = " + result.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();    
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation for " + user + " failed ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be useful.

Comment: You will need to post more code than this. Where are user and computer defined?

Comment: Is Type.GetTypeFromProgID(objectName) null?

Comment: You might want to consider System.DirectoryServices for this instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx. The way you are doing it is analagous to how you do it in VBScript. You can use the DirectoryEntry UserFlags property to set/unset Enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to handle this exception and why my objectName is null here?

`objectName` is not going to be `null`. The more likely scenario is that `Type.GetTypeFromProgID(objectName)` is *returning* null, because that prog-id doesn't exist, or the account doesn't have access.

Check what `Type.GetTypeFromProgID(objectName)` returns, and act accordingly. Make sure it is actually a prog-id, and that you are using that API correctly. For example:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(objectName);
if(type == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
    "Invalid prog-id: " + objectName);
dynamic objUser = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

---

Edit: Note that `Activator.CreateInstance` etc is **not** the same as VBScript's `GetObject`. To access that, reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`, and use:

```
dynamic obj = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject(objectName);
```

Comment: Invalid prog-id: WinNT://./John,user. This what prog-id returns. Why the user John is not being called from the group user?

Comment: @user1528803 to answer that, I'd need to see where it says that is *supposed* to work...